# Can I get back data after setting up root to iSCSI device?

Tags: 11.04, iscsi

I tried to setup iSCSI target and defined `root` partition as target (that was wrong I know).

I didn't format the iSCSI device; is it possible to get back the data from this partition? System does *not* boot at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could establish a root filesystem in an iSCSI target but you would need to do a good number of things to make that possible.  It seems like you were using the blockio method (raw filesystem).  I suggest you look-up the fileio method as it will be a little safer for you relative to your experience (no offense intended).

To get the data back from a raw filesystem (used by iSCSI) you would need to move the disk to a working system, establish an iSCSI target for that partition and then connect to it from any initiator.

Good luck.